# flutter Issue in getting subcollection from document in firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an issue, I can't get subcollection from the document:
I have firestore db with
collection: collectionName
Inside collection documents and inside one document subcollection "items"

1. collectionName

   - Document1

     - Items <- subcollection

       - Item1
       - Item2

I use the following code but the items subcollection can't be retrieved from my db....`

````
```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('collectionName')
      .orderBy("order")
      .getDocuments();
```
`then`

```
snapshot.documents.forEach((document) {})
```
````

The document doesn't have the items subcollection

Answer (score 0):

You can not access a sub-collection like that. Last year, the team working at firestore released a new feature called the **Collection Group**. If you want to access the items collections try doing this:

```
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('items')
```

This will contain all documents in the items sub-collection regardless of how deeply nested it is. Take a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) for more information on collection groups.

Comment: Thank you @eandpi for the reply, The issue that I need to load all the documents from firebase with all its subcollection at app loading. if you have a sample or tutorial for such issue in flutter, please let me know